# Unable to discard output from redirection followed by &

Tags: bash, pipe

In the instruction containing a redirection, neither of `1` or `2` or nothing, on the lhs of `>/dev/null` discards the output, in this case `[24] 1073640`. This is contrary to my expectation, What could I be misunderstanding? Also what does `[24]` represent?

```
$ uname -r
6.7.3-arch1-2
$ PIPE=$(mktemp -u)
$ mkfifo "$PIPE"
$ python > "$PIPE" 1>/dev/null & # EXPECTED: no output
[24] 1073640
$ python_id=$!
$ printf "python_id=%s\n" "$python_id"
python_id=1073640
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator ‘&’, the shell
> executes the command asynchronously in a subshell.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html:

> ($!) Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into
> the background,

Answer (score 1):

The `[24] 1073640` is not output by the program; it's output by your shell to indicate that it's tracking the background job. In this case `24` is the internal job ID assigned by your shell (just a convenience shortcut) while `1073640` is the real process ID.

Interactive shells typically track all background jobs so that you could resume them and so that the shell could notify you when the job is done; e.g. running `jobs` will list all jobs in that shell, while `fg 24` or the shortcut `%24` would bring the job to foreground.

(This doesn't happen in shell scripts.)

If you want to untrack an already tracked job, `disown` it; if you want to prevent a command from being tracked as a job, 1) consider whether it should've been started as a service instead, 2) if not, then run it inside a subshell as `(foo &)`; 3) consider again whether it should be a service.

`(foo&)` works because the `(..)` will spawn a new shell process, which won't be able to carry over job information to the main process. Another option is `setsid foo` which works for a different reason.

Your command probably should have had `2>` instead of `1>`, as file descriptor #1 is already what `>` operates on by default (meaning that your command was redundantly redirecting stdout twice, but doing nothing about stderr).

Comment: I started a process for python with a view to a) source function definitions b) make iterative calls to these functions. I have a feeling`$(python > "$PIPE" &)` would defeat the purpose.